# JDBC Could not establish SSL connection (Domino Java Agent FP 9) to SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc, jvm

I have a Java Agent running on a Domino Server.  It was running fine on version Domino 9.0.1 FP7.  The MS Windows server is 2003.  Waiting on SQL server version.

*Now we upgraded the Domino Server to 9.0.1 FP9. The JVM went from 1.6 to 1.8.*

I am assuming this Exception error is caused by the JVM or Java Policy because I upgraded the JDBC driver from 4.2 to 6.2.2 trying to fix this with no success (same error).

Connection String Original (JDBC Driver ...jvm/lib/ext/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar)

```
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER";
```

Connection String Same Result (JDBC Driver ...jvm/lib/ext/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar) - added encrypt=false.

```
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER:1433;encrypt=false;";
```

**The Exception**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:e8a3a2c4-d9a9-4f82-a63f-967cae0c29f0".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2435)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1816)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2022)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:675)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:258)
    at OrderTrackOrders.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:e8a3a2c4-d9a9-4f82-a63f-967cae0c29f0
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:774)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:830)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:821)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1003)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:991)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:272)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:148)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:19)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.at.i(at.java:627)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:689)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.at.startHandshake(at.java:432)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1753)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Has the SQL Server been configured to force protocol encryption?  Are there any more details about the login failure in the SQL Log?

Comment: Ms windows 2003 server.  I will report back once I find out the SQL server version.  If O/S does not support TLS 1.2, what are my options?

Comment: You really shouldn't change things on an out-of-support operating system.  If Force Encryption is set on the SQL Server, perhaps you can turn that off and connect without encryption.

Comment: That is an idea, do I have to be concerned with other processes that maybe connecting with SSL? For example web servers, will other things break expecting SSL?

Comment: @david, can you look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007778/hibernate-writing-oriental-instead-of-latin-symbols-into-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to Domino FeaturePack 9 this agent ran fine on FP6 and FP8.

This is a security issue related to disabled TLS security cyphers in the FP9 java.security file when connecting to a MS SQL server running on Windows 2003 server.

The solution is to make this change in the java.security file 'Domino Program Dir/jvm/lib/security/java.security'
Change these two lines to remove 3DES_EDE_CBC, DESede
From:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, 3DES_EDE_CBC, DESede, \ EC keySize < 224
```

To:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, EC keySize < 224
```

Feature Pack 9 makes the following changes to the java.security file in the Domino Program directory on the server: 
Domino Program Dir/jvm/lib/security/java.security

Change 1 
Prior to FP9:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024
```

Updated in FP9:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \ 
    DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224
```

Change 2 
Prior to FP9: `jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024` 
Updated in FP9: `jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024`

Change 3 
Prior to FP9: `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768` 
Updated in FP9:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, 3DES_EDE_CBC, DESede, \ 
    EC keySize < 224
```

Change 4 (the following entries are NEW in FP9)

```
jdk.xml.dsig.secureValidationPolicy=\ 
disallowAlg http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116,\ 
disallowAlg http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-md5,\ 
disallowAlg http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-md5,\ 
disallowAlg http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#md5,\ 
maxTransforms 5,\ 
maxReferences 30,\ 
disallowReferenceUriSchemes file http https,\ 
minKeySize RSA 1024,\ 
minKeySize DSA 1024,\ 
noDuplicateIds,\ 
noRetrievalMethodLoops 

sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter=javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out java.security, try to comment disabled ciphers (I cannot get exact property now, search for SSL), or this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/11/30/intermittent-jdbc-connectivity-issue-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption-error-sql-server-returned-an-incomplete-respons/

Real solution would be to test 1433 with openssl and check what encryption settings should be used.

Comment: Thanks, this put us on the right track.  Tom documented the detailed fix.